# Setup file orientation for documents to print

Tags: vb.net, printers

I'm creating VB application where i want to print documents, but all of my documents have different orientation, some of them are in portrait orientation and some of them are in landscape.

I have a function where user can print bunch of files, like more then one which have different orientation.

This is the code which I use to set the settings of the printer programmatically:

```
Dim Printers As PrinterSettings.StringCollection
Printers = printerSettings.InstalledPrinters
Dim printerSettings As New PrinterSettings

printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pageSettings.PaperSize
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution = pageSettings.PrinterResolution
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Color = pageSettings.Color
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = pageSettings.Landscape
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings = printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings
printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = pageSettings.PaperSource
```

I can setup the orientation here: pageSettings.Landscape, but it will be only landscape or only portrait. I want to be automatically detected?

Is that possible?

If not, is there a way to check file orientation before print the file programmatically with VB?

I try to add auto to the: `pageSettings.Landscape` but it accepts only true/false.

Comment: What kind of documents?  How are you printing them?

Answer (score -1):

This will print files using the orientation specified in the file.

```
Private Sub PrintFile(FileToPrint As String)
    Dim myFile As New ProcessStartInfo
    With myFile
        .UseShellExecute = True
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        .FileName = FileToPrint
        .Verb = "Print"
    End With
    Process.Start(myFile)
End Sub
```